# Is there a way to merge two form array controls?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have two  form arrays in my code. I need to combine them and perform addition and deletion on the combined array. 
I need to concatenate the form array controls of each form array

```
let a = this.nextBillForm.controls["electricityBillCycleEnergyCharges"] as FormArray;
let b = this.nextBillForm.controls["electricityBillCycleOtherCharges"] as FormArray;
```

1)populate by for each

```
a.forEach(element => {
  b.push(element);
});
```

2) concatenation

```
 a.concat(b)
```

Tried both ways. Both show errors

Comment: Try to use ES6 spread (...) operator!

Comment: What kind of error are you getting while doing those?

Comment: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) : please explain what you want to achieve, instead of asking help on a solution you think is the right one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FormArray` is not an array. It doesn't have `forEach` nor `concat` functions. You can operate on `controls` property though:

```
a.controls.forEach(control => {
 b.push(control);
});
```

or

```
const combined = a.controls.concat(b.controls);
```

See [FormArray documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Nat_centralogic Both the ways that you have tried will not work because the form Array object is not an Array reference.
It is the reference of form group. FormArray reference does not any method like concat or push i.e. why it is throwing errors.

See in the image below:

[image]

Although by name it is obious to think it is array but it is not.

As a solution either you can link all items to single fromArray or use them sapratly to avoid complexity.